# Use glob patterns in bitbucket pipelines for matching semantic tags

Tags: bitbucket, glob, bitbucket-pipelines

I'd like to trigger different pipelines by matching tag semantics in Bitbucket pipelines. Globbing seems to work only for `*` matchings, but other features from glob patterns seem to not be taken:

`+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9])`

for instance. This should match every tags like `1.0.0`, but not anything else.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

I'd prefer not to trigger any pipeline, make the check in the pipeline script and exit early.

```yaml
pipelines:
  tags:
    +([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9]):
       name: Pipeline for new semantic tag
       script:
         - ...
```

Note: I also tried putting the glob between `"`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no regex support for tags, it's all [simple globs](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-glob-patterns-on-the-pipelines-yaml-file/)

Does this work for you?

- '*.*.*'
- build-*
- build-*.*.*
- release-*
- release-*.*.*

Comment: The example in the question is a valid glob and I tested it with other glob matchers. But yes, indeed, seems like Bitbucket only supports "simple" globs, that is `*` expansion only. Unfortunately, I would need verifications on character ranges (e.g. verify that numbers are used, and not alphabetical characters).

Comment: @VladRusu is it possible to verify the number at the time of creating the tags?

Comment: Well, yes, that's already done. But I want to start 2 different pipelines: one when a semantic tag has been generated, and another one when a manual/dev tag has been pushed.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but if you can't get by with pattern matching you could fail the step if it doesn't match your regex...

something like this should work:

```
[[ $BITBUCKET_TAG =~ ^+([0-9]).+([0-9]).+([0-9])$ ]] && echo "valid tag" || exit 1
```

Comment: Yup, I was trying to avoid that. It is so ugly to start a pipeline which just fails at the first step.